# javascript calculator to decimal places and images as button

Tags: javascript, calculator

i have a small javascript form

```
<div id="calculator-text"><h2>Tape calculator - based on cable size 1 mm to 28 mm, with 15% overlap</h2></div>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">

<div id="calcformlabel"><label for="val2">Enter your cable size</label> (in mm)</div>
<div id="calcformtext1"><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"></div>

<div id="calcformbutton"><input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate"></div>

<div id="calcformresult">The tape size you require is:- <span id="result1" class="maintext1"></span> (mm)</div>


</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById('calculate');
btn.onclick = function() {
    // get the input values
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('val2').value);

    // get the elements to hold the results
    var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');

    // create an empty array to hold error messages
    var msg = [];
    // check each input value, and add an error message
    // to the array if it's not a number
    if (isNaN(val2)) {
        msg.push('<span class="maintext1">Enter your cable size</span>');
    }
    // if the array contains any values, display the error message(s)
    // as a comma-separated string in the first <span> element
    if (msg.length > 0) {
        result1.innerHTML = msg.join(', ');
    } else {
        // otherwise display the results in the <span> elements
        result1.innerHTML = val2 * 3.142 * 1.15;
    }
};
</script>
```

basically this is a simple calculation

a) how can i get this to output to 2 decimal places (and obviously round up or down depending on -.5 = round down  and +.5 = round up)

b) replace the input type button for an image ( i have tried the obvious  code and >input type = image>, basically these do actually work but instead of displaying the actual result, they display the result in a split second then reload the page with the blank form again...

any help on this would be much appreaciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**for a part of your question**

you can round javascript to specific precision by

[**Link :Number rounding in JavaScript**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml)

var original=28.453

```
1) //round "original" to two decimals
var result=Math.round(original*100)/100  //returns 28.45
```

```
2) // round "original" to 1 decimal
var result=Math.round(original*10)/10  //returns 28.5
```

```
3) //round 8.111111 to 3 decimals
var result=Math.round(8.111111*1000)/1000  //returns 8.111
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`.toFixed()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) lets you round off to *n* decimal places, so:

```
result1.innerHTML = (val2 * 3.142 * 1.15).toFixed(2);
```

I think the problem you're having with the image is that `<input type="image">` defines the image as a *submit* button. Perhaps just include a standard image with an `<img>` tag rather than `<input type="image">`. If you give it an `id='calculate'` it should still work with your existing JS.

Or you could use a button element containing an img element so that you can specify the type (as not being submit):

```
<button type="button" id="calculate"><img src="yourimage"></button>
```

(I'm not sure that you need a form at all for this functionality since you don't seem to want to submit anything back to the server.)

Comment: brilliant, thanks nnnnnn for the 2 decimal places fix, and regarding the button, i didnt realise i could put an id to a <a ref image... thanks again

Comment: You can give an id to any element, so yes, an anchor element containing an image would also work.

Answer (score 0):

To swap the button for an image, replace the button <input> with this code:

```
<img src="http://www.raiseakitten.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/kitten.jpg" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();" />
```

It adds the image and a submit function for your form.

To round to two decimal places, use this function:

```
function twoDP(x){
     return Math.round(x*100)/100
}
```

use it like this:

```
twoDP(100/3)   //returns 33.33
```

it might also be relevant for you to use Math.PI

```
var result = val2 * Math.PI * 1.15 ;
```

Comment: replace the <input type="button"> element